# Let's pull the plug on [plugins]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

The [plugins](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/plugins) tag is not very specific to any question. It doesn't add any information as to what the question might be about and is very vague and overall useless.

Comment: I wouldn't call it vague or useless, but I find it hard to see the existence of an "expert" on *all* plugins, making this tag look more like a meta-tag.

Comment: I'd always rather see a more specific tag, `vim-plugins` for example, so I say we 'upgrade' it's usage rather than eliminating it.

Comment: Good point Gordon. If someone is asking about firefox plugins then they should be looking at firefox-plugins, or confluence-plugins. The drawback there is that you can't then group all answers to the generic 'plugins'. Instead of a search of [plugins] it would be a search for [*-plugins ] which for some reason resolves to [vim-plugins] when searching from the search box in superuser.com. As an interim step using both could be tried, so an article would have [firefox] [plugins] [firefox-plugins] and statistics could be drawn to see which approach is better?

Answer (score 2):

I would go a step up to your request and remove all X-plugins tags. Normally X is a tag already created and applied to these posts, so it makes little sense to have a question tagged [firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox) and [firefox-plugins](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox-plugins) or [eclipse](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) and [eclipse-plugins](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugins).

Comment: I agree with removing "plugins" generically but "firefox-plugins" is not the same thing at all as "firefox".

Comment: @mikebabcock I know they are NPAPI plugins, but hey, is weird when the plugin doesn't work with all applications that supports NPAPI.